# ms sql server full text index option not active

Tags: sql-server

In my MS SQL Server Management studio the `Full-Text index` option is disabled. Even after i use command bellow to enable it. Any idea how to fix it? Note i am using SQL Management studio 18.1 and SQL server 2017 express.

```
Use MyTestDb
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
```

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/12157477-5d0e-4ff1-a0b2-df86b7639664/sql-server-express-advanced-services-fulltext-search?forum=sqlexpress.

Comment: Did you install SQL Server Express, or SQL Server Express with Advanced Services? The former does not support Full-text Searches: [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2017 - Programmability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017#Programmability) (see Full-text and semantic search).

Answer (score 0):

I went here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

I then downloaded the DEVELOPER version and went through the add features option. There's a tickbox for installing Full Text Search services. I didn't need to reboot - when I opened SSMS again the option was there.